# To predict rare event classification, is there any "more simple" way than using LSTM Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am currently working on rare event prediction, which I have never done before (I used to work with simple prediction problem), and I looked up on [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/extreme-rare-event-classification-using-autoencoders-in-keras-a565b386f098) about using LSTM for time series rare event classification.

It was very exciting to read since I think my case is a little similar: to predict calving time of cow, with historical activity feature, where calving is only happen once in the end of data collection.

However... aside from my data is way smaller than the example, I got too much confusion using LSTM. The good point about LSTM I am looking forward to is the "look back" feature that can let you decide for each output how many input in previous time you look back to.

My question will be: is there any "easier" or more simple machine learning method that works like LSTM for time series classification?

I tried to use simple ML such as decision tree, random forest, but I don't think it represents the problem well (many historical data into one output).

This question is cross-posted on StackExchange too. I am aware that I should be asking more programming related question here but any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: You could try the ARMA family of models.

Comment: When you say 'easier', do you mean something that is cheaper on your computer's processing power?

Comment: @Andrew it is more to something work on smaller datasets and is easier to understand how it works on my data, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a lot of machine learning projects/programs is the lack of data, which you have stated is one reason you wish to not use an LSTM. Not only for LSTM's (although these are greatly impacted as well), but other methods you run into problems such as over-fitting your data, higher importance being placed on outliers, etc., something that can really only be fixed with more data (or fine tuning of parameters).

One option you could look into could be synthetic data generation, or a different method to grow your data set.  That way you would still be able to use an LSTM, as it would have more data to run on.

I will link to an [article](https://medium.com/rants-on-machine-learning/what-to-do-with-small-data-d253254d1a89) I found helpful in covering the problems with small data.  Your best bet is to go with a simple, or rather basic ML approach (linear regression is an example).

One option you could try is an SVM if you want to try and separate the rare prediction from the more standard pattern (don't know much about your data set so hard to say).

If you want to pick out the variance, i.e. rare prediction, you could also try using a PCA and see where the highest variance is.

Again, the methods I have suggested depends heavily on your data set, and I am not sure how effective they will be with your time series data. Finding a way to enlarge your data set would be the preferable option.

Let me know if this was helpful!